# Get selectmenu name and title while submitting the form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to get the title of the selectmenu when submitting the form.
I am using the below code. But its not giving the value.

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
    $('.required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (!input) {
          $(".ui-selectmenu").addClass( "required" );
          var msg = input.attr('title');
          alert(msg);
          $(".ui-selectmenu").after('<ul class="error"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
        }
    });
});
```

**Selectmenu**

```
$('select.class1:not(select.class2)').selectmenu({
    style:'dropdown',
    maxHeight: 300,
    transferClasses: true
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="test" name="test" class="required class1" title="Please select to continue.">
```

This alert is giving me empty value. Any help on this?
Thanks

Comment: probably when you are activating the selectemenu plugin it hides your existing select menu and costructs a new one. But it does not transfer the title attribute. When you select the visible select menu $('.required').filter(':visible'), it selects the one without title, because the plugin hides yours.

Comment: try $('.required')find(":selected") instead of $('.required').filter(':visible')

Comment: So how can I get the title of the select?

Comment: Hi Sindhu..Thanks for your reply. I need to actually iterate through all the dropdowns and check if empty, If empty throw display error. That is why I used $('.required').filter(':visible') . I have updated my question. If I use your answer, I will not be able to highlight the error when its value is null. Is there any other way I can achieve both?Can you please check that and advice me?